# How to skip the first n batch documents during an aggregate command?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I run this command :

```
db.runCommand( 

  {
    aggregate:"myColl",
    pipeline:[
      {
        $group:{
          _id:{_id:"$_id"},
          count:{$sum:NumberInt(1)}}
      }
    ],
    cursor:{}
  }

 )
```

it's return me something like:

```
{ 
    "cursor" : {
        "firstBatch" : [
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "_id" : NumberLong(-9223365602644598416)
                }, 
                "count" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "_id" : NumberLong(-9223363178405875157)
                }, 
                "count" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "_id" : NumberLong(-9223350896770545240)
                }, 
                "count" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "_id" : NumberLong(-9223338355283447904)
                }, 
                "count" : 1.0
            }, 
            ....
        ], 
        "id" : NumberLong(4379399839731469797), 
        "ns" : "myDatabase.myColl"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

now I would like the instruct to the command the **number of batch documents to skip** and also the **number of batch documents to returns**. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
db.runCommand(

    {
        aggregate: "myColl",
        pipeline: [
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { _id: "$_id" },
                    count: { $sum: NumberInt(1) }
                }
            },
            { $skip: n } // n should be a positive integer, where n documents are skipped
        ],
        cursor: { "batchSize": n } // n should be a number, it denotes the batch size.
    }
)
```